# Symfony валидация форм

Tags: php, symfony2

Ввожу 123 - получаю Не может быть пустым!
Ввожу 123а - получаю This value is not valid.

Сущность:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="intfield", type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="Не может быть пустым!"
     * )
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="int",
     *     message="Должно быть число!"
     * )
     *
     */
    private $intfield;
...
```

Контроллер и создание формы:

```
    /**
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/register"
     * )
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('intfield', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //...
        }

        return $this->render('@App/register/register.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измени тип форм на IntegerType.

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('intfield', IntegerType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
```

Comment: Та хотел без стрелок (вверх/вниз) поле, решил проблему с помощью regex

Comment: Ты можешь изменить виджет и будет без стрелок.

Comment: Забыл сразу. Ты можешь создать свой тип форм и он будет как текстовое, но вводить туда можно будет только int.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.